# How to correctly create a component that can handle a value and an observable of this value

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have in fact two questions.

When should I pass a observable of an object into a component and when should I resolved it with the `| async` method?

I also need if i want to propose a robust reusable component to handle the two cases. so i want to be able to take as an input an **observable** or just the resolved **value** directly.
What is the solution inside the component to handle these two cases?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the easer way is use a setter in your Input, if the input is an observable just work with this observable else using rxjs operator `of` to convert to Observable

A fool example

```
import {Observable,of,isObservable} from 'rxjs';
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `
  <pre>{{obs|async}}
  `
})
export class HelloComponent  {
  obs:Observable<any>
  
  @Input() set data(value){
    this.obs=value instanceof Observable?value:of(value)
    //or, thanks to Vikas
    //this.obs=isObservable(value)?value:of(value)

  }
}
```

the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4ucg1b?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**Update** Well, we can think in another way. If received an observable, we subscribe and equal a variable to the data received. else equal the variable to the input.

A fool example without stackblitz

```
import {isObservable,Subscription} from 'rxjs';
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `
  <div *ngIf="yet">
     <pre>{{obs}}</pre>
  </div>
  `
})
export class HelloComponent implements OnDestroy  {
  obs:any
  yet:boolean=false; //a optional variable
  subscription: Subscription //<--here store the subscription
  @Input() set data(value){
    if (isObservable(value)){
        if (this.subscription)
            this.subscription.unsubscribe();

        this.subscription=value.subscribe(res=>{
           this.obs=res;
           this.yet=true
        })
    }
    else{
       this.yet=true
       obs=value
    }
  }
  ngOnDestroy(){
      if (this.subscription){
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
        this.subscription=null
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm , We can also use `isObservable()` https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/isObservable

Comment: @Vikas Sure, and thanks: I didn't know this function

Comment: As a word of warning, if you're going to do this and only use the async pipe to susbcribe to the observable, you're fine. If you call `subscribe` yourself on it anywhere this can leak subscriptions because handling unsubscription isn't trivial here anymore.

Comment: Thx to the proposal! But i'm not sure it responds in the good way to my question. If we use your solution, we will transform some **not async** value into **async** observable. I think it is messy to do it in this way. I search a solution to resolve the potential observable and not create new one if it is a **synchronized** value.
Anyway i didn't received an answer for the first question, if any of you have an idea! :)

Comment: @ilphrine, Well, we always can think in the other way: if we received an observable, subscribe to get the data (I update the answer)

Comment: Ok clearly better for me :) I found something like this but in fact it is pain in the ass to still check if the **obs** value is resolve. Anyway you find a clear solution with your **yet** boolean. thx